# Extended use of Rewrite Module in Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I have a website in one language, and now I have to translate it to another, and according to some practices that I have to follow, I should create subdirectories whose name should be the translation of that conecpt into the new language.
I want to reuse the same code I have using some PHP variable to switch form one language to the other, but for that I would like to retain the subdertories names and maybe use Rewrite to create "fake" translations of the subdirectories name??

In other words if I have http://www.mysite.com/information/index.php, for the new language I should have for example http://www.mysite.com/LANGUAGE/INFORMATION TRANSLATED IN ANOTHER LANGUAGE/index.php

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance,
   Alejandro